# Laravel scope with inner join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, search, inner-join

I have 2 tables, `projects` and `jobs`. `jobs` has a column called `project_id`. In Laravel 5.2 I want to run a search that will return all jobs which belong to a project of a given search term. This SQL works:

```
SELECT jobs.*, projects.name FROM jobs INNER JOIN projects ON jobs.project_id = projects.id WHERE projects.name LIKE "%$keyword%"
```

In my `Job.php` model I have created a scope method, which errors:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $keyword)
{
    if ($keyword != '') {
        $query->where(function($query) use ($keyword) {
            $query->where('projects.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')->join('projects', 'jobs.project_id', '=', 'projects.id');
        });
    }
    return $query;
}
```

This produces the error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'projects.name' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `jobs` where (`projects`.`name` LIKE
>   %test%))

In my `JobsController.php` I have:

```
$searchResults = Job::Search($searchTerm)->get();
```

Comment: Can you post the query builder statement in your controller? You just be using it if you created the scope in your model

Comment: Ah, thanks. I actually didn't scroll over in your scope which identified the issue. Seems as though you cannot add joins in nested where clauses. Try removing the nesting and just use the line starting with $query->where('projects.name... In your of statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter `$query` in `where(function($query)` is not the `$query` that you passed in `public function scopeSearch($query, $keyword)`

You can either remove it with just the query like below (as @Rob mentioned)

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $keyword)
{
    if ($keyword != '') {
        $query->where('projects.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')->join('projects', 'jobs.project_id', '=', 'projects.id');
    }
    return $query;
}
```

or you need to include the `$query` in use()

```
$query->where(function() use ($keyword, $query)
```